# working with nested arrays hashes ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, nested, hash

I'm having a hard time with nested hashes

```
 Restaurant = {:name=>"McDonalds",
 :location=>"NYC",
 :chefs=>
  [{:name=>"Sunny", :food=>"fries"},
   {:name=>"Brooklyn", :food=>"burgers"},
   {:name=>"Mac", :food=>"burgers"}],
 :waiters=>
  [{:name=>"Jess", :role=>"senior manager"},
   {:name=>"Sam", :role=>"manager"},
   {:name=>"Jack", :role=>"server"},
   {:name=>"Mary", :role=>"server"}]}
```

how would I delete the waiter hash with Jack as a value for example?
or return all waiter's names with the role of server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Restaurant[:waiters].reject!{|h| h[:name] == "Jack"}
Restaurant # => {
  :name=>"McDonalds", :location=>"NYC",
  :chefs=>[{:name=>"Sunny", :food=>"fries"}, {:name=>"Brooklyn", :food=>"burgers"}, {:name=>"Mac", :food=>"burgers"}],
  :waiters=>[{:name=>"Jess", :role=>"senior manager"}, {:name=>"Sam", :role=>"manager"}, {:name=>"Mary", :role=>"server"}]
}

Restaurant[:waiters].select{|h| h[:role] == "server"}
# => [{:name=>"Mary", :role=>"server"}]
```

Comment: I think you posted the output of another version of your code.  There is more than one waiter that has the role = "server".

Comment: @7stud It is continuous. After `"Jack"` has been deleted, there is only `"Mary"`.

Comment: `Restaurant[:waiters].find{|h| h[:name] == "Jack"}[:role] = "manager"`

Comment: Thanks! Also, how do you print out all the elements in the array since you can't just simply puts it.

Comment: Have you considered of accepting an answer before keep adding new questions?

Comment: Ah I see! Sorry about that! Thanks!

Comment: May be you can open a new question about your addition question.